# Dynamically created button width is not changing

Tags: android, button

Can somebody tell me why my button width is not increasing .what am i doing wrong.
I am trying to create button dynamically and set their width and height.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout l;
    LinearLayout linear;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        l=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);






        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
             linear=new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams par=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            linear.setLayoutParams(par);
            linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            Button b=new Button(this);



            b.setId(i+1);
            b.setText("button:"+(i+1));
            b.setWidth(800);// set the width of button
            b.setHeight(30);// height of button


            linear.addView(b);

            l.addView(linear);  // main layout in which i have to show button
        }


    }


}
```

here is the output : what i am getting
enter image description here

[image]

Comment: Keep format your code and post Image again.

Answer (score 1):

To increase automatically your button width you can use wrap_content.

You can use this code to set LayoutParams programmatically

Put this:

```
b.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

before this:

```
linear.addView(b);
```

Comment: Not working exactly. dont know why this is happening

Comment: Try using MATCH_PARENT instead of wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

Add dynamic button with LayoutParams as below code,

```
Button b=new Button(this);
b.setId(i+1);
b.setText("button:"+(i+1));

LayoutParams lp1 = new LayoutParams(800,30);
linear.addView(b, lp1);
```

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/ehhm6o/8 This is what i am getting as  per your code here</a>

Comment: You can modify code according to your requirements. I have given only logic.

Answer (score 0):

Give the buttons layout width and height as you did for the LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Also in this case you dont need to add the buttons in `linear` (LinearLayout) since you are adding them first to `linear`, and then adding `linear` to `l` in the same loop. Each LinearLayout(linear) will only hold one button, and no need for that. Either add all the buttons to `linear` and when the loops finish you add them to `l`(just once) or dont create 'linear' and add them directly to `l`

What you can do it this to make it more simple:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        Button b=new Button(this);
        b.setId(i+1);
        b.setText("button:"+(i+1));
        b.setWidth(800);// set the width of button
        b.setHeight(30);// height of button
        b.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        l.addView(b);  // main layout in which i have to show button
    }
```